# Transfer file from android to server via socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

There is such a problem. To transfer files in an Android application, we use a Socket, we encrypt and transfer to the server, there the data is decrypted and transmitted by the usual POST method, but when some data is transferred, the file is not loaded, but returns 500 The error stream terminated unexpectedly. One xlsx file is transferred. but the other is gone. We also saw that if the file is still uploaded to the server and we download it, the file is broken and at the end a piece of header Content-Disposition: form-data; name = "publicAccess" false.

**ANDROID CODE**

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            byte[] request = new byte[4096];
            byte[] reply = new byte[8192];
            final InputStream inFromClient = sClient.getInputStream();
            final OutputStream outToClient = sClient.getOutputStream();
            SSLSocket remoteSocket = tlsConnectionService.createSSLSocket(remoteHost, remotePort);
            final InputStream inFromServer = remoteSocket.getInputStream();
            final OutputStream outToServer = remoteSocket.getOutputStream();
            // a new thread for uploading to the server
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    int bytes_read;
                    try {
                        while ((bytes_read = inFromClient.read(request)) != -1 ) {
                            String newReq = new String(request);
                            if (newReq != null) {
                                outToServer.write(newReq.replace(LOCAL_SOCKET_URL, remoteHost).getBytes(), 0, bytes_read);
                                outToServer.flush();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        if (!(e instanceof SocketException)) {
                            Log.e(M.CPP, e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.start();
            // current thread manages streams from server to client (DOWNLOAD)
            int bytes_read;
            try {
                while ((bytes_read = inFromServer.read(reply)) != -1 ) {
                    outToClient.write(reply, 0, bytes_read);
                    outToClient.flush();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(M.CPP, e.toString());
            } finally {
                try {
                    remoteSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(M.CPP, e.toString());
                } 
            }
            sClient.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(M.CPP, e.toString());
        }
    }
```

**Server CODE**

```
@PostMapping(
            value = {"/file", "/file/" },
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
    )
    public ResponseEntity<FileEntryDto> upload(
            @PathVariable("source") String source,
            @AuthenticationPrincipal JwtUserDetails currentUser,
            @Validated FileUploadRequest request
    ) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(
                converters.fileToDto(
                        fileOperationService.upload(Source.fromName(source), request, currentUser.getUserId()))
        );
    }
```

The request that we see when inspecting app
[request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Reejr.jpg)

Comment: You use two input streams in your code. Why? How can you have infromserver and infromclient? Please explain how your setup works.

Comment: Inside the android application, a proxy server is used. It receives data from the application itself through the input stream (inFromClient) and transmits it through the outputstream (outToServer), to receive a response from the server, the same thing is only inFromServer and outToClient.